# Como aplicar funções recursivas?

Tags: c#

Criar um programa em  c# que permita mediante o uso de função recursiva, determinar a quantidade de vezes que aparece a letra B em uma palavra inserida pelo usuário.

Comment: Você fez algum código?

Comment: não fiz ainda! @VirgilioNovic eu nunca usei função recursiva , preciso de Ajuda.

Comment: Você sabe o que é função recursiva?

Comment: Sei ! Mais nunca usei...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente uma [função recursiva](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) é aquele que invoca assim mesma até que uma determinada condição satisfaça, no caso da sua pergunta parece que o exercício é varrer letra a letra até o seu fim, então um código abaixo para exemplificar como passar a ler letra a letra e retornar esse novo texto para que seja verificado novamente, até não ter mais texto, *exemplo*:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static int Count(string word, string letter)
    {   
        if (word.Length > 0){           
            if (letter == word.Substring(0,1))
            {
                return 1 + Count(word.Substring(1), letter);
            }
            else 
            { 
                return Count(word.Substring(1), letter);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        string palavra = "bcb0ç";
        System.Console.WriteLine(Count(palavra, "b"));
    }
}
```

Um outro código sugere um melhor desempenho utilizando [indexOf](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8), onde a ocorrência for maior que `-1` o valor foi encontrado e pula para o próxima pesquisa se tem mais algum índice maior que `-1` e assim por diante limitando a pesquisa na busca somente do valor procurado:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static int Count(string word, string letter)
    {   
        if (word.Length > 0){           
            int index = word.IndexOf(letter);
            if (index > -1) 
            {
                return 1 + Count(word.Substring(index + 1), letter);
            }           
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        string palavra = "bcc0b00bb";
        System.Console.WriteLine(Count(palavra, "b"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Percebi!! Muito obrigado @Virgilio_Novic